# Run thread while jframe is running

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe

I'm trying to run some codes in background, while main frame is running. But when ı run below code, jframe is opening but can not do anything until thread finished. My main method is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            CheckLicense license = new CheckLicense();
            boolean check = license.checkUpdateStatus();
            if (!check) {
                HMessageBoxForLicenseControl control = new HMessageBoxForLicenseControl(null, null,
                        ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL,
                        TextResources.getInstance().getResourceValue("systemNotification"),
                        TextResources.getInstance().getResourceValue("licenseTimeOver"));
                control.setVisible(true);

            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    // System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");

    MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
    window.frame.setVisible(true);

}
```